# AWS Getting Authenticated Identity PoolCredentials

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

I have an web app where a Cognito user will log in and then needs access to S3 and DynamoDB resources. I have an identity pool configured with auth and unauth roles, but I only need to use the authenticated role as I don't want guest users to be able to sign up or use the app.

After logging in with a Cognito User, I'm creating CognitoAWSCredentials so I can access the resources I need:

```
 CognitoAWSCredentials identityPoolCreds = new CognitoAWSCredentials(accountID, identityPoolID, unauthRole, authRole, EUWest);
```

As long as I grant S3FullAccess to the unauthRole it works, but when I grant it only to the authRole it throws an "Access Denied". When I prevent access to the unauthRole from within the AWS Console, it throws an "Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool" error. So, it looks as though its always trying to use the unauthenticated role. How do I get it to use the authenticated role? I've already logged a user in earlier in the process, but I'm not passing any data from that user to the CognitoAWSCredentials, which is possibly the problem?

Comment: If you are using the AmazonS3FullAccess IAM Policy, that grants all S3 actions to all S3 resources in your account.  It would allow Cognito users to read, modify, and delete "everything" and very likely result in a future security breach.

Comment: @KevinHakanson - yes, I had granted full access. What I hadn't done is add the login to the credentials, so I was access the data using the unauthenticated user. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding a login to the credentials:

```
        CognitoAWSCredentials creds = new CognitoAWSCredentials(identityPoolID, region);

        string providerName = $"cognito-idp.{region.SystemName}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolID}";

        creds.AddLogin(
            providerName,
            user.JWTID);
```

The user.JWTID is given in the response to the cognito user login:

```
AuthFlowResponse authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
if (authResponse.AuthenticationResult != null)
{
  user.JWTIT = authResponse.AuthenticationResult.IdToken
...
```

Hope this helps someone!